# Как подключить плагин "Letter Effects" js, jqery

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, плагин

Кто может объяснить как [его](https://tympanus.net/Development/LetterEffects/#section1) использовать? 
в демо исходниках есть такие строчки:

```
// Initialize
        var txt = new TextFx(this.el.querySelector('.title'));

// Show letters: 
     // txt.show([effect] [,callback]);
```

так понимаю верх это пример инициализации, а снизу пример использования "показать" вот но нет документации или я не нашел, что подставлять в "effect" ? callback так понимаю можно пропустить.

мой код выглядит как то так:

**html:**

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

**js:**

```
var txt = new TextFx($('h1'));

txt.show();
```

Файлы плагина подключаю в таком порядке:

```
'libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
/libs/letterEffects-master/js/charming.min.js', 
'libs/letterEffects-master/js/anime.min.js', 
'libs/letterEffects-master/js/lineMaker.js', 
'libs/letterEffects-master/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', 
'libs/letterEffects-master/js/textfx.js',
'js/common.js', // мой файл скрипта где неудачно пытаюсь вызвать плагин)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Во-первых**

> подставлять в "effect" callback так понимаю можно пропустить.

Да можно, но анимации не будет.

> If nothing is passed, then no animation.

**Во-вторых**, `TextFx()` не ест jQuery объекты, поэтому так:

```
var txt = new TextFx( $('.title')[0] );
```

**И в-третьих**, чтобы объект показать, нужно его сначала скрыть:

```
txt.hide() //тут как раз без анимации
txt.show('fx1')
```

```js
(function() {

  var txt = new TextFx( $('.title')[0] );

  txt.hide()
  txt.show('fx1')

})();
```

```css
.title {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/LetterEffects/js/charming.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/LetterEffects/js/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/LetterEffects/js/lineMaker.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/LetterEffects/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/LetterEffects/js/textfx.js"></script>

<div class="title">Тестовый заголовок</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за направление на путь истинный) а то я тупанул, правильно я понимаю? это не есть плагин, а просто примеры реализации эффектов, с использованием *нескольких* плагинов? в том числе anime.js у которого кроссбраузерность ие10+ по тому пожалуй эффект который я хотел сделать (выпадение букв по очереди сверху вниз лучше сделать с нуля) уже так и сделал, циклом перебрал каждую букву внутри h1 засунул ее вo spanы jsом и по очереди top с opacity анимирую, "animate" в jqery понимает ие9 что есть хорошо. Если я в чем то не прав буду рад совету, или подсказке альтернативной реализации. Благодарю!

Comment: @junior-web-dev возможно да, загружать тучу библиотек, чтобы сделать одну довольно простую анимацию слишком жирно для интернет-трафика

Comment: есть идеи почему ваша анимация fx1 отличается от анимации в примере?

Answer (score 2):

Решил написать с нуля *(вдруг кому пригодиться)* :

```
<h1>Привет мир</h1>

//letterEffect(element,speed,delay);

function letterEffect (element,speed,delay){
    element.css("opacity","0");
    setTimeout(function(){
    element.css("opacity","1");
    var el = element;
    var sp = speed;
    var output = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < el.text().length; i++) {
        if(el.text()[i] != " "){
            output = output + '<span class="js-letters">'+el.text()[i]+'</span>';
        }
        else{
            output = output +" ";
        }

    }
el.html(output);
el.children(".js-letters").css({
    position: "relative",
    top: "-20px",
    opacity: 0
})

var countLetterAnim = 0;
anim();
function anim ()
{
        $(el.children(".js-letters")[countLetterAnim]).animate({
        top: "0px",
        opacity: 1
    },sp,function(){
        if(el.text().length != countLetterAnim){
            countLetterAnim++
            anim()
        }
        sp = sp - sp / 100 
    });
}
},
delay);

}


letterEffect($("h1"), 200, 300);
```